# Matching bean id with instance member variable in java code for @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

I have below bean defined in application context xml file:

```
<bean id="logRoutingTable" class="com.symantec.cas.ucf.plugin.router.RoutingTable">
  </bean>
```

And using it in java file with `@Autowired`

```
@Autowired
private RoutingTable routingTable;
```

The above code is working properly. But now I realized that instance name `routingTable` is different than bean id `logRoutingTable`. So is it not necessary to match both bean id and instance member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not required. The instance variable can have any name. Spring framework automatically searches for matching bean. In case you have more than one bean for same class then you have to use

```
@Qualifier("beanName")
```

for matching by bean Name.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is only one bean matching (IS-A) RoutingTable, Spring will allow the injection.

If you had another bean matching, there would be a conflict that you could solve with @Qualifier([See mykong example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/)) or by renaming the instance variable to match the bean id.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have only one bean for RoutingTable.